# Create a remote copy of linux server filesystem

Tags: linux, backup

I have a decommissioned server (VPS server with a hosting company) that I need to backup before we close our account. I don't need to run the server anywhere else, I just need a browse-able copy of all the files. What's the best way to get a copy of the server's filesystem based off ssh access?

VPS is a Debian distro.

Comment: Please tell us what OS type you are running.

Comment: rsync of the relevant directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are endless!  The big three:

- `rsync` the system to a remote storage location
  (`man rsync` -- Too many sub-options to list, but `rsync -azH` is probably a good start)
- `tar` everything up and shove it over SSH
  `tar cf - | ssh some-other-location tar xf -`
  -- Obviously you don't have to extract to the other location, you can keep it in a tarball, compress it before it goes over the network, etc.
- Use your backup software to cut a "final archive"
  You ***do*** have backup software, right?  So you can just cut a full backup and archive it.
  (If you don't have backup software, ***[GET SOME](http://www.bacula.org/)***.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

```
rsync -avzH root@remoteserver:/ /local/folder
```

- -a archive
- -v verbose
- -z compression
- -H preserve hard links

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw a block level copy into the ring:

You can use `dd` and `nc` to mirror the whole disk if you'd like.

On your receiving server, open up a listening port and redirect the output to a file.

`nc -l someportnumber | dd of=/tmp/diskimage`

On the VPS, read the disk with `dd` and redirect the output to your remote server.

`dd if=/dev/sda | nc remote.server.hostname someportnumber`